# Known issues with delayed messages in RabbitMQ

Tags: timer, rabbitmq, delayed-job

I'm considering delayed messages plugin as a solution of a distributed timer.
The message is a *command* and the execution of the command is delayed.

I'm wondering if there are any known issues with the delayed message rabbitmq plugin?  Is it something that can handle a scale of thousands messages per minute?
Or maybe there is some better solution for the use-case I described above?

Comment: `delayed messages plugin` do you mean https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange ?

Comment: @Gabriele - yes, that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange` plugin does store the messages in Mnesia.

The plugin generally works fine, but you should be careful about the limitations.

Please read the limitation section https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange#limitations

And also the performance section: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange#performance-impact

> housands messages per minute

It is not an high value, but it depends how many messages you need to store and also the payload size